# how to calculate this and insert to existing column in mysql

Tags: mysql

my mysql table(loan) have paidamount,rental,date and age columns,i'm stuck with this caculation how i do

```
Age=(paidamount/rental)-((datetimenow()-date)7)
```

and insert it to the age column..?

Answer (score 1):

You use `update`:

```
update loan
    set age = (paidamount / rental) - datediff(curdate(), date) / 7;
```

Comment: it,s not " * 7" it,s "/7"

Comment: @isurulakshan . . . That would have been my guess, but it is not what your question says.